How to start spawn-fcgi socket via systemd in Ubuntu?
I'm using spawn-fcgi for a site on nginx in ubuntu.
I start the socket with the following command:
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/fcgiwrap.sock -M 755 -u www-data -g www-data /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap

How can I start this process via systemd? So that it starts automatically after the server is rebooted.

I'm sure there are plenty of existing posts about creating a systemd service? spawn-fcgi doesn't look like it needs any special treatment as far as creating a .service goes.
